# Can we print an array like this?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define N (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))

main()
{
   int array[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
   int d;
   for(d=-1;d <= N;d++)
       printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);
   return 0;
}
```

The above code is not displaying anything? Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: Use formatting to make your code more readable! Also consider rephrasing your question: what do you mean with "can"?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your problem is? Is it with the loop? With the definition of `N`? Something else?

Comment: Nt is wrongly entered...It is N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll note in passing that the code as it stands will read outside the bounds of the array, since `d+1` will be `6` at the last iteration of the loop, while the highest valid array index is `4`. But this isn't the main problem with your code; as it stands, when `d = -1`, the condition `d <= N` will actually evaluate to `false`, and thus the loop terminates at once without going through any iterations. The problem is that the result of the expression  `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` is of type `size_t`, which is an *unsigned* integer, while `d` is an `int`, i.e. a *signed* integer. Prior to the actual comparison, `d` is converted to a `size_t` (this is called *type promotion*), resulting in a *large positive integer*, and thus the expression `d <= N` evaluates to false. See [this](http://c-faq.com/expr/preservingrules.html) c-faq entry for more information. To really drive the point home, you may want to try the following code, and see if it works as expected:

```
int d = -1;
printf("%u\n", d); 

size_t n = 5000;
if (d > n) printf("oops!\n");
```

Fixing your code is fairly simple - for example, as others have suggested, rewriting the loop as

```
for (d = 0; d < N; d++) {
        printf("%d\n", array[d]);    
}
```

will work.

Comment: yeah..this is correct. As I checked the type of N which comes out to be unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

You can do any kind of mumbo jombo magic play with the indexes as long as the effective value of index evaluates in such a way that you dreference the array in valid ranges.

Your code does finally resolves to a valid index range i.e: `0` to `4` and so it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

d ranges from -1 to 5 inclusive, so you access array[0] through array[6] ... or you would, except that the value of `sizeof` is of type `unsigned`, so -1 <= N is false.

Answer (score 0):

No, because:
Where are you define Nt?
**Nt undeclared**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by `Nt` you mean `N`, then yes, it should work.

Comment: No, it shouldn't, and it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Well this looks like a valid format to print, but in the `for(d=-1;d <= Nt;d++)` I think you meant N, which you have defined in macro

Answer (score 0):

array almost started form [0] and end to the [n-1]
here use array int and declare d variable.
can u print array entered style then arr[0] start them.

for(d=0;d<=array[5-1];d++)/*declare for loop*/

printf("%d",array[d];/*print the array in sequence */

Comment: Your "English" here is incomprehensible. Also, please use the code block mechanism to format code so that it indents properly.